# return separate values from an array in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an instance variable `@seats` in a controller having value as follows (I checked the value using a byebug breakpoint)

```
#<Programmability::Response:0x007fdae0bb84e8 @return_code=0, @outputs=[[2, 4]], @table=#<Programmability::Table:0x007fdae0bb8538 @rows=nil, @columns=["column1", "column2"]>>
```

How do i display the following in JSON

```
column1: 2
column2: 4
```

I have the following line in JSON which returns `output: [[2, 4]]`

```
json.output        @seats.blank? ? nil : @seats.outputs
```

Comment: Is the `.output` part forcing the values into the `output` key?

Comment: what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
@seats.outputs.flatten.each_with_index do |val,index|
  puts "column#{index+1}: #{val}"
end
```

Comment: This literally outputs it. That's not the desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> I have following line in json which returns output: [[2, 4]]

```
json.output        @seats.blank? ? nil : @seats.outputs
```

I'm guessing you are already using `jbuilder` templates. If so, to get the output you mentioned above, I think you can do something like this in your jbuilder template:

```
json.output do
  @seats.outputs.each_with_index |col, ndx|
    json.set! "column#{ndx}", col
  end
end
```

I have not tested this but it would seem to work based on the docs here: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder